# ValueError: '/anaconda3/lib/libpython3.6.dylib' does not exist

Tags: python-3.x, macos, py2app

I'm working on creating an app from Python code using py2app.

Everything goes well until I run setup.py, then at the very end of it running I get this message: "ValueError:

```
ValueError: '/anaconda3/lib/libpython3.6.dylib' does not exist
```

It turns out there is a file there, just named slightly different: It asks for 'libpython3.6.dylib' and there is a file named 'libpython3.6m.dylib'

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you find a solution for this?